# Sending 2 message separately using socket

Tags: python, sockets

I want to send 2 messages separately using `socket`. My code so far is below.

Server end:

```
from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 8888))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
msg1 = conn.recv(128).decode()
print('msg1', msg1)
msg2 = conn.recv(128).decode()
print('msg2', msg2)
```

Client end:

```
from socket import *

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 8888))
msg1 = "hello"
sock.sendall(msg1.encode())
msg2 = "world"
sock.sendall(msg2.encode())
```

The terminal prints the following:

```
msg1 helloworld
msg2
```

What I expected was 2 messages received separately, and for them to be printed like this:

```
msg1 hello
msg2 world
```

How can I change my code to get what I want?

Answer (score 5):

You have to either a) only read the amount of information you want to display, or b) block before sending the second message from the client.

**A**

```
msg1 = conn.recv(5).decode()
print('msg1', msg1)
msg2 = conn.recv(5).decode()
print('msg2', msg2)
```

**B**

(server)

```
msg1 = conn.recv(128).decode()
print('msg1', msg1)
conn.send(b'Hi')
msg2 = conn.recv(128).decode()
print('msg2', msg2)
```

(client)

```
msg1 = "hello"
sock.sendall(msg1.encode())
sock.recv(2048)  # but we don't really care what the message is
msg2 = "world"
sock.sendall(msg2.encode())
```